# How to create resuable methods for Tables in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: xpath

I need to work with tables by using reusable method for different table. We have two different types of tables as below

```
    <div id="grid">
    <div class="header">
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <tr>

<div id="grid">
<div class="header">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
```

how can i write a common method for these two.

i would like to have some thing like..

//div[@id='Grid']/div/table/tbody or thead.

i would like to just pass the table id like

//div[@id='"+tableId+"']/div/table/tbody or thead

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use use '|' for 'or'

//div[@id='"+tableId+"']/div/table/tbody|//div[@id='"+tableId+"']/div/table/thead